# Synonyms which don't work

Tags: discussion, tags

While looking through some of the tags pertaining to the MCU, I noticed there is a tag synonym for [captain-america](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america) which points to [captain-america-the-first-avenger](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-the-first-avenger), meaning the movie itself. I find this *sort of* problematic. The issue as I see it is, we have and are getting much more of an amalgamation of characters throughout the MCU which are crossing over into the other movies. This is especially true for [avengers-infinity-wars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-infinity-wars). The problem lies in what if someone wants to ask a question specific to the Captain in Infinity Wars and yet differentiate it from The First Avenger? The tag synonym as it stands for [captain-america](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america) will not allow you to do that.

My suggestion is, we somehow specify between the character and the movie they originate from when the two could be. For instance using [captain-america-character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-character), [black-panther-character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-panther-character), [iron-man-character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-man-character), or [thor-character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thor-character) (to name a few) which would fully differentiate the character from their respective movie.

I'm sure there are other examples of this type of thing where it would be good to differentiate the character from the movie itself. This is just an obvious cross pollination of characters within the MCU where we should be able to specify for this. I'm trying to lay down a general rule which would allow us a bit of consistency when dealing with the characters versus their respective introductory movie.

Answer (score 4):

We **don't really do specific character tags** on this site. They tend to turn into a mess, one we set out to clean up a long time ago and have largely cleaned up. So I would very much advise against creating tags for each and every MCU hero (or any other kind of character). In general the approach of this site is largely work- or franchise-centric, rather than character- or universe-centric. These things can of course intertwine and overlap quite a lot, but there's a fundamental difference to the viewpoints.

If your question is about Captain America's behaviour in *Infinity War* specifically, [avengers-infinity-war](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-infinity-war) is sufficient, maybe with the general [character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) tag if it's a question inherently about his character, or also [plot-explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) if it's just about some story unclarity, or a combination thereof. If it's *not* about a specific film only, then we still have the general [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) tag anyway.

I agree, though, that the tag [captain-america](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america) is a little confusing there. It's likely an artifact of the past, when [captain-america-the-first-avenger](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-the-first-avenger) was too long for a tag. This tag, however, has only ever been a tag for the very film rather than the character of Captain America in general. But...it's also not even necessary anymore as a synonym for the film, since typing `cap...` into the tag list already brings up [captain-america-the-first-avenger](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-the-first-avenger) anyway. So we can just remove it and turn down the confusion a little.

Comment: The problem lies, though, if you separate the current synonym for [tag:captain-america] from the current movie tag, you then bring ambiguity back into the situation. I want to ask a specific question having to do with the Captain, which pertains to Infinity Wars, yet as it stands cannot properly tag the question as such. If you just delete the synonym, then yes, I could use it, but it then becomes problematic going back to the original movie.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 But you can, you tag it `avengers-infinity-war`? No, if I delete the synonym you *cannot* use it, it's deleted. The point is that you just don't tag the question with the character it's about and the `captain-america` tag never served that purpose. I understand why you think it does, and that confusion is solved by just getting rid of it.

Comment: If you delete the synonym (which is the tie between the two tags), you are just disassociating the tags, not destroying [tag:captain-america]. And if you deleted [tag:captain-america] altogether, the tag itself can be recreated by anyone with the ability to create tags.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It can, but it shouldn't, since we don't do character tags on this site. If it is, the helpful editors can remove it from the question. But, that's the case with any tags users accidentally create.